# ASP.NET MVC: how to return a file from a stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, dotnetzip

I'm trying to return a zipped file

```
public FileResult Download()
        {
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddEntry("asdasd.html", "<html>fgdfg</html>");
                    zip.AddEntry("asdassssd.html", "<html>asddsaf</html>");
                    zip.Save(outputStream);
                }

               return File(outputStream, "application/zip", "file.zip");
}
```

but in response it returns an error (in XML):

> > XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
> >     moz-nullprincipal:{122aa411-1418-43f5-b950-4347af7c7217} Line Number
> >     1, Column 1:

What is wrong with my response (to zip files i use DotNetZip)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to reset the MemoryStream to the beginning of its buffer before you return it to the client as a File.

```
outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

I also suggest you use a proxy like Fiddler to inspect the Http response to get a better handle on what exactly your request is sending.

Comment: Still no file.. In Fiddler in RawView: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2011 11:25:56 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hey.zip
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 422
Connection: Close

PK����<s?��e&������
�$�asdasd.html
� �����������Pb�����Pb�����Pb���(�ͱ�I�O��KKOIK���m���PK����<s?������!����$�asdassssd.html
� �������M4��Pb�M4��Pb�M4��Pb���(�ͱ�I�O��K,NI)NL���l��R�PK-�����<s?��e&         and so on..

Comment: I have found the problem: I should call  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "File")?params=' + allVals; rather then $.post (....) And of cause to add outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); Thank you!